# Automapper map properties to complex object

Tags: automapper

I have a class called "Destination", and a class call "Other" with this structure:

```
public class Destination
{
     public int Id { get;set;}
     public Other First { get;set;}
     public Other Second { get;set;}
}

public class Other
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public string Address { get;set;}
}
```

And I have a third class which is my source Type and I want to map it to class Destination

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    public int FirstId { get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get;set;}
    public string FirstAddress { get;set;}

    public int SecondId { get;set;}
    public string SecondName { get;set;}
    public string SecondAddress { get;set;}
}
```

How should I config automapper to auto map "Source" to type "Destination"?

Comment: https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers